# How to make left and right formulas on one slide perfectly symmetrical with tabular?

Tags: beamer, tabularx

Please I have two formulas with two tables and I want to distribute the two left and right completely symmetrically, like this:

[image]
I wrote a minimal working code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} 
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(0.5cm,1.5cm) 
                ABC = DEF
            
        \resizebox{1.0\linewidth}{!}{   
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                    \hline
                    A & B & C & D \\ \hline \hline
                    a  & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0 \\  \\
                    b & 0.1&0 & 0\\ \\
                    c  & 0.2&0  & 0 \\ \\
                    d  & 0.3&0 &0 \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}
        \end{textblock*}
    
   \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(6cm,1.5cm) 
           ABC = DEF    
        \resizebox{1.0\linewidth}{!}{   
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            \hline
            A & B & C & D \\ \hline \hline
            a  & 0.1 & 0.2 & 0 \\  \\
            b & 0.1&0 & 0\\ \\
            c  & 0.2&0  & 0 \\ \\
            d  & 0.3&0 &0 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{textblock*}    
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### What should I do to be the same as the example picture, and additionally, I want to know how to make the data in the first column correspond to the data in the second and third columns of two rows, and center it up and down, I try to use  `\makecell {0.1\0.2}` but it produces an extra border which is not what I want. thanks

[image: f5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use already implemented `columns` environment in `beamer`, which splits a frame into regions, and centre the content of each column.

Note, `\\` accepts an optional argument `[<length>]` if you want to increase vertical spacing between rows: `\\[<length>]`; the negative value decreases spacing, instead.

If you want to resize the table, it's better to change the font size from the regular `\normalsize` to `\large`, `\Large` or `\LARGE`, etc. This is a switch so whatever comes afterwards will be affected. However, the changes will only be local to an enclosing environment, that is `column` in the example.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \setlength\jot{3pt}
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \(
        ABC = DEF
      \)
      
      \vspace{2\baselineskip}%
      \begin{tabular}{*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}}}
        \hline
        \thead*{A} & \thead{B}  & \thead{C}   & \thead{D} \\
        \hline \hline
        a & \makecell*{0.1\\0.2} & \makecell*{0.3\\0.4} & e \\
        \hline
        b & \makecell*{0.1\\0.2} & \makecell*{0.3\\0.4} & f \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \(
        ABC = DEF
      \)

      \vspace{2\baselineskip}%
      \begin{tabular}{*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}}}
        \hline
        \thead*{A} & \thead{B}  & \thead{C}   & \thead{D} \\
        \hline \hline
        a & \makecell*{0.1\\0.2} & \makecell*{0.3\\0.4} & e \\
        \hline
        b & \makecell*{0.1\\0.2} & \makecell*{0.3\\0.4} & f \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I have placed them symmetrically under your guidance, the description inside the table is misunderstood due to my poor English level. I've added a hand-drawn schematic picture to the question, that is, each data in the first and fourth columns corresponds to the two data in the second and third columns, and is centered up and down.

Comment: No worries. You actually post a screenshot (the first one) which resembles almost what you wanted to accomplish, which I missed as I focused on the code. You were almost there with `\makecell` but missed the double `\\`. The answer is updated.

Comment: It worked,，thank you very much！